# Trying to retrieve image in a viewholder class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm working on an open-source messaging app, and the class that takes cares of showing my contact list and as well as generating their avatars and names is a viewholder class and not an activity. Therefore, I get an error saying that Firebase can't connect. I already have an uploading firebase feature working, and now I want to retrieve these pics. If I'm not wrong I think firebase upload/fetch methods HAVE to be in an activity class right? Because viewholder classes don't have oncreate methods to initialize the variables.

How can I retrieve all users' profile pics if that's the class that's taking care of it?
It goes through all the try-catch bracket but it doesn't connect.

Here is what I tried doing, but I get a token error.

```
public class ContactItemViewHolder<I extends ContactItem>
    extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
..
..
StorageReference storageRef, riversRef;
private Bitmap myImage;
FirebaseStorage storage;

protected void bind(I item, @Nullable OnContactClickListener<I> listener) {
        Author author = item.getContact().getAuthor();
        //accessing the firebase storage
        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        //creates a storage reference
        storageRef = storage.getReference();
        riversRef=storageRef.child(author.getName() + "/pic");
        String contactName = author.getName();
        name.setText(contactName);
        try{
            File localFile = File.createTempFile("images", "jpg");
            riversRef.getFile(localFile)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            // Successfully downloaded data to local file
                            // ...
                            myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localFile.getAbsolutePath());
                            Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(myImage);
                            avatar.setImageDrawable(d);

                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    // Handle failed download
                    // ...
                }
            });
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
```

Comment: try using FirebaseUI approach - https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

Comment: not too familiar with glide. Is it a tool that lets me download from storage, or is it just to show a slide of pics?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is, load firebase data directly into recyclerview or make a model class with all the attributes you need and plug the data in the recyclerview's parent class. As Firebase is asynchronous you can set adapter of the recyclerview in the OnSuccessListener and it will load recyclerview at once when the data is fetched.